# Error with the destructor of a 3D dynamic array of cells

Tags: c++, graphics, cell, destructor, dynamic-arrays

I'm working on a graphic project and I want to implement a 3D grid where each cell is a class, so I can store the necessary information. I'd like to use dynamic arrays, thus, according to other questions found here, I wrote this code:

```
class Cell {
 public:
    Cell(const Eigen::Vector3i& idx=Eigen::Vector3i::Zero()):
        _idx(idx){
        _parent = 0;
        _distance = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    }

    inline bool operator < (const Cell& c){
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
            if (_idx[i]<c._idx[i])
                return true;
            if (_idx[i]>c._idx[i])
                return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

    Eigen::Vector3i _idx;
    Cell* _parent;
    float _distance;
};

class DenseGrid {
 public:
    DenseGrid(float resolution_=0,
        const Eigen::Vector3i& size_=Eigen::Vector3i::Zero(),
            const Eigen::Vector3f& origin_=Eigen::Vector3f::Zero()):
                _resolution(resolution_),_size(size_),_origin(origin_) {

        _inverse_resolution = 1./_resolution;
        _num_cells = _size.x()*_size.y()*_size.z();
        _data = new Cell[_num_cells];
        _ptrs = new Cell**[_size.x()];
        for(size_t x=0; x < _size.x(); x++) {
        _ptrs[x] = new Cell*[_size.y()];
        for(size_t y=0; y < _size.y(); y++) {
            _ptrs[x][y] = _data + y*_size.z() + x*_size.y()*_size.z();
        }
        }
    }
    ~DenseGrid() {
        delete [] _data;
        for(size_t x=0; x < _size.x(); x++) {
        for(size_t y=0; y < _size.y(); y++) {
            delete [] _ptrs[x][y];
        }
        delete [] _ptrs[x];
        }
        delete [] _ptrs;
    }

    inline Cell* data(){return _data;}
    inline int numCells(){return _num_cells;}

 protected:
    Eigen::Vector3f _origin;
    float _resolution;
    float _inverse_resolution;
    Eigen::Vector3i _size;
    int _num_cells;
    Cell* _data;
    Cell*** _ptrs;

};
```

when I try to use this class with a basic example, I get a runtime error:

> *** Error in `./signed_distance_function': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x0000000001802010 ***
>
> Aborted

which I suppose is caused by the destructor. Please, could someone tell me where is the mistake?

Thanks,
Federico

---

EDIT

This is how I test the code:

```
#include "three_d_grid.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    Eigen::Vector3f orig(0,0,0);
    float res = 0.25;
    Eigen::Vector3i size(3,3,3);
    DenseGrid dg(res,size,orig);

    int n = dg.numCells();
    Cell* data = new Cell[n];

    for(size_t idx=0; idx < n; idx++)
        cout << data[idx]._idx.transpose() << "\t";
    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

---

EDIT 2

@Anto: I followed your advice and the error disappeared, so the correct way is

```
DenseGrid::~DenseGrid() {
    for(size_t x=0; x < _size.x(); x++) {
        delete [] _ptrs[x];
    }
    delete [] _ptrs;
    delete [] _data;

}
```

??

Comment: We may be able to help you if you provide a [mcve]. That said, my crystal ball tells me that there is something wrong with your manual memory management. Did you remember to implement the copy/move constructor/assignment operator?

Comment: Just because the error occurs in the destructor it doesn't mean that's where the bug is. You need to show a [mcve]. Most likely, your bug is that you failed to follow [the rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29#Rule_of_Three).

Comment: You have 3 allocation with `new sthg[]` and 4 deallocation with `delete []`. Line `delete [] _ptrs[x][y];` could be redundant, and maybe `delete [] _data;` should be moved to the end of destructor.

Comment: Why not use RAII classes as `std::vector` or `std::unique_ptr` and get rid of manual deallocation ?

Comment: Seems that an `Cell& getCellAt(int x, int y, int z)` would be better than this `Cell*** _ptrs;`.